# Is there any way to avoid these $with models from loading whenever loading the parent in Laravel 5.7 Eloquent?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-5.7

I have a `laravel` application in which I have Models using $with, in the frontend whenever I load this Model it loads its child's $with as well. Can you guys tell me how to avoid that?

Below is an example for you guys to understand the scenario.

```
ModelA.php
$with = [ModelK, ModelL, ModelM];
```

```
ModelK.php
$with = [ModelM, ModelN];
```

```
ModelM.php
$with = [ModelX, ModelY, ModelZ];
```

In my frontend, wherever I use `ModelA` with eloquent, it makes query on `ModelM`, `ModelX` both. This is making my site slow. Also if I retrieve 4-5 rows data from `ModelA` then it also make runs queries on all these models `ModelM`, `ModelX` and that too one query for each row. So the number of queries is also increase.

The relationship between these models are One-One, One-Many and Many-Many.

Is there any way to avoid these child Models whenever loading the parent?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `$with` property in your models, you can disable the eagerLoading within a query with the following:

```
ModelA::setEagerLoads([])->first();
```